# Changing a URL based on anchor link clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a menu that links to anchors on the page (all built in WordPress). For example:

```
<nav id="primary">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <section id="services">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</section>
  <section id="about">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</section>
  <section id="portfolio">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</section>
  <section id="blog">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</section>
</div>
```

The anchor IDs also correlate to the slug names on my site.

I'm creating a floating sidebar that will have content that changes based on the section that is clicked. The floating sidebar will obviously stay fixed on the side of the container as you scroll through the page.

For instance, when clicking on "About", the floating sidebar might say "learn more about XYZ" which links to the about page. I'll likely use custom fields on each of the pages to generate the text in the floating sidebar.

My problem is getting this to function, where the text and link in the floating sidebar changes based on the link in the navigation that is clicked. Getting the dynamic text and links from my pages is not needed, I can figure that out later using WordPress functions.

I'm not sure how to go about this...maybe jQuery is the right solution? if so I just don't know how to implement it.

**EDIT** I've attempted to implement some of the suggestions below. My current HTML and JS are as follows:
HTML

```
<header class="site-header">
    <nav class="nav-primary">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#services" data-href="/services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about" data-href="/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio" data-href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#blog" data-href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="site-inner">
    <div class="content-site-wrap">
        <section id="services">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</section>
        <section id="about">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</section>
        <section id="portfolio">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</section>
        <section id="blog">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</section>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('click', '.nav-primary a', function(){
    html = $('<a href="' + $(this).data('href') + '">' + $(this) + '</a>');
    $('.site-inner').html(html);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

understand, for what your case is similar to jquery tabs is only REQUIRED to make some changes.

http://www.findsourcecode.com/css/jquery-how-to-create-simple-tabs-using-jquery-and-css/

excuse me if this is not

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`data-attributes`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

HTML

```
<nav id="primary">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#services" data-description="About Services" data-href="/services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" data-description="About Us" data-href="/about">About</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
</nav>

<div id="sidebar"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).on('click', '#primary a', function(){
    html = $('<a href="' + $(this).data('href') + '">' + $(this).data('description') + '</a>');
    $('#sidebar').html(html);
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I'm not able to get this to work entirely, changing the link doesn't work, despite using the code you suggested. I've updated the question with my current code. TIA

Comment: @NWTech you're using data-attributes in your JS but haven't added them to your markup. Please see a demo here http://fiddle.jshell.net/TW3tp/1/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want the solution, you can accomplish this via css only.  With a `label` and a `radio button` you can have a the ability to toggle the visibility of elements making it look like the options are changing.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwuNc/2/) example